# Showing already upvoted for the newly created user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, react-fullstack

This is blog full stack website. Only registered users can upvote and comment. When user is registered he should be able to upvote. But when I run the app and create new user, the button always says Already upvoted.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {useParams}  from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import NotFoundPage from './NotFoundPage';
import CommentsList from '../components/CommentsList';
import articles from './article-content';
import useUser from '../hooks/useUser';
import AddCommentForm from '../components/AddCommentForm';

const ArticlePage = () => {

    // using destructuring assignment to extract the articleId parameter value from the current route using the useParams()
    const {articleId} = useParams();
    const [articleInfo, setArticleInfo] =   useState({ upvotes: 0, comments: [], canUpvote: false });
    const { canUpvote  }    = articleInfo;
    const { user, isLoading } = useUser();

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadArticleInfo = async () => {
            const token = user && await user.getIdToken();
            const headers = token ? { authToken: token } : {};
            const response = await axios.get(`/api/articles/${articleId}`,{headers});
            const newArticleInfo = response.data;

            setArticleInfo(newArticleInfo)
            
        };

        if(isLoading){
            loadArticleInfo();
        }
    }, [isLoading, user, articleId]);
   
    // used the .find() method on the articles array, which returns the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.
    const article = articles.find(article => article.name === articleId);

    const addUpvote = async () => {
        const token = user && await user.getIdToken();
        const headers = token ? { authToken: token } : {};
        const response = await axios.put(`/api/articles/${articleId}/upvote`, null, {headers});
        const updatedArticleInfo = response.data;
        setArticleInfo(updatedArticleInfo);
    };

    if(!article) {

        return <NotFoundPage />;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{article.title}</h1>
            <div className="upvotes-section">
            {   user ? (
                <button onClick={addUpvote}>
                    {canUpvote ? 'Upvote' : 'Already Upvoted'}
                </button> 
                ) : (
                <button>Log in to upvote</button>
            )}
                <p>  This article has {articleInfo.upvotes} upvote(s).</p>
            </div>
            {/* the .map() method is called on the article.content array, and for each paragraph in the array, it returns a <p> element with the paragraph as its content */}
            {article.content.map((paragraph, i) => (  
                <p key={i}>{paragraph}</p>
            ))}
            {user
                ?<AddCommentForm articleName={articleId} onArticleUpdate={updatedArticle => setArticleInfo(updatedArticle)} />
                :<button>Log in to add a comment</button>
            }
            
            <CommentsList comments={articleInfo.comments} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default ArticlePage;
```

When I create a new user, it shows Already Upvoted. But it should show Upvote option.

This is my server.js file

```
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs'
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import {db, connectDb} from './db.js';

const credentials = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync('./credentials.json')
);
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(credentials)
});

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use(async(req, res, next) => {    

    const {authToken} = req.headers;

    if(authToken) {
        try{
            req.user = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(authToken);
        }catch(err) {
            return res.sendStatus(400);
        }
    }

    req.user = req.user || {};
    next();
});


app.get('/api/articles/:name', async (req, res) => {

    const {name} = req.params;
    const {uid} = req.user;

    const article = await db.collection('articles').findOne({ name }); 

    if(article) {
        const upvotesIds = article.upvotesIds || [];
        article.canUpvote = uid && !upvotesIds.includes(uid);
        res.json(article);
    }else{
        res.status(404).send('Article not found!');
    }

});

app.use(( req, res, next) => {

    if(req.user) {
        next();
    }else{
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
});


app.put('/api/articles/:name/upvote',async (req, res) => {

    const {name} = req.params;
    const {uid} = req.user;

    const article = await db.collection('articles').findOne({ name }); 

    if(article) {
        const upvotesIds = article.upvotesIds || [];
        const canUpvote = uid && !upvotesIds.includes(uid);

        if(canUpvote) {
            await db.collection('articles').updateOne({ name }, {
                '$inc': {
                    'upvotes': 1
                },
                '$push': {
                    'upvotesIds': uid
                }
            });
        }
        const updatedArticle = await db.collection('articles').findOne({ name });
        res.json(updatedArticle);
    } else{
        res.status(404).send('The Article does not found!');
    }
});

app.post('/api/articles/:name/comments', async (req, res) => {

    const {name} = req.params;
    const { comment } = req.body;
    const {email} = req.user;

    await db.collection('articles').updateOne({ name }, {
        '$push': {
            'comments': {
                postedBy:  email,
                comment
            }
        }
    });

    const article = await db.collection('articles').findOne({ name });
    
    if(article) {
       
        res.json(article);
    }else{
        res.status(404).send('The Article not found!');
    }
});

connectDb(() => {

    console.log('Connected to Database!');
    app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('Server is listening on port 8000!');
    });
});
```

I tried change loadArticleInfo inside useEffect but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

`.canUpvote` is never updated to `true` on the frontend, so the ternary will always be false.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: There needs to be an indicator of whether the user is logged in. Then you can define article info this way: ```const [articleInfo, setArticleInfo] =   useState({ upvotes: 0, comments: [], canUpvote: userLoggedIn ? true : false });```